# Phone Authentication firebase in Ionic v3 with cordova-plugin-firebase

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, plugins, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement login in my ionic v3 application by the firebase phone authentication service.

I've read several tutorials. Between them:

1- https://javebratt.com/firebase-phone-authentication/

2- https://github.com/jestcastro/cordova-plugin-firebase#f778505942bbf7518df75545c6a6b32efa4d5229

-

The comments in link 1 teach how to use the cordova-plugin-firebase of link 2.
I tried to do the documentation. I did everything exactly the same, as it is said in the links.

Yet,
When I use the function ( window).FirebasePlugin.getVerificationID, from link 2, gives the error: ERROR TypeError: Can not read property 'getVerificationID' of undefined

I did exactly the same. And I've been trying to solve this problem for a few days. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Hi Carlos, did you find a solution for this question. Even I am trying to implement Phone Authentication in Ionic 3 and could not find any useful link. Any suggestion will be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

I think the cordova-plugin-firebase is for ionic v1. When you have ionic v3 in use, then you will use the cordova-plugin-fcm.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.

In case, it does not work?
Or does cordova-plugin-fcm work?

I looked at the cordova-plugin-fcm and it seemed to be just to handle notifications. I do not quite understand how it fits into phone authentication.